# Fragment over other fragment appearing after coming from background

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the below code which make use of bottom navigation and display 3 different fragments. The code runs perfectly. But the issue is sometimes when the application is in background for too long and the user comes back to the screen , the first fragment is displayed perfectly but on click of the second and third tab the view get distorted i-e content of the first and and second or first and third fragments appears overlapped.

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private final Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment1();
private final Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment2();
private final Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment3();
private final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();

private Fragment active = fragment1;

private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
        = item -> {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment1).commit();
                    active = fragment1;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment2).commit();
                    active = fragment2;
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    fm.beginTransaction().hide(active).show(fragment3).commit();
                    active = fragment3;
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        };


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);

    //Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new MyExceptionHandler(this));

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment3, "3").hide(fragment3).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment2, "2").hide(fragment2).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, fragment1, "1").commit();

}
```

}

How to resolve this ? Any help

Comment: Rather than using hide , you should use replace in fragment transaction

Comment: replace will destory the fragment and recreating it is an extensive job for us as there will be multiple api calls

Answer (score 0):

You can add only one fragment at an onCreate time after on click of bottom navigation only replace a fragment and in your XML file not add any fragment class.

```
private final BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = item -> {
                switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case R.id.navigation_home:
                       setFragment(new fragment1());

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                        setFragment(new fragment2());

                        return true;
                    case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                       setFragment(new fragment3());

                        return true;
                }
                return false;
            };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_screen);


        BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.add(android.R.id.content, fragment1);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

    protected void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();


       }
```

Comment: The problem why I didnt use this approach is when the data in the first fragment load I have a dependency to update the data in the second fragment as well . In that case the application will crash as there will be no fragment avaialble

Comment: if you want to update data into the second fragment you can use an onFragmentVisible method. which is called every time when the fragment is visible to the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

create a view for fragment transaction

```
<FrameLayout
   .....
    android:layout_above="@+id/navigation"
   ....
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView/>
```

and in your class replace the frame layout with fragment
using

```
 private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    if(fragment!=null ) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
        .addToBackStack(null)
        .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment)
        .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The second item in this answer is most likely what is producing the visual effect you describe (one fragment on top of the other), but points 1 and 3 are also imporant aspect you should consider.

**1) Holding on to the Fragment instances.**

As instances can be destroyed and recreated, instead of holding on fragment instances (`fragment1`, `fragment1`, `fragment3`), just keep a reference to the fragment tag string.
The way you have it now, the fragment on screen may be a different instance than the one you are holding on in the activity that in fact should have been garbage collected. (a memory leak)

When you need to do something with the fragment, use `SupportFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(theGragmentTag);`

**2) Fragmet creation in the Activity's onCreate**

In the activity's `onCreate(savedBundle)`, create the `fragments` only when `savedBundle` is null. Otherwise Fragments will start duplicating and most likely show the behaviour you describe of one on top of the other.

**3) Fragments can be destroyed while in backaground**

Assume the fragment may be destroyed when it is not on screen so save and restore the info you need. Save in `onPause()`, restore depending on your needs: `onResume()`, `setUserVisibleHint(boolean)`

Note: If the UI should be refreshed when the fragment becomes visible, `onResume()` alone won't do the job because it may have already been called when its neighbour fragment became visible. In this situation you will need to combine `onResume()` with `setUserVisibleHint(true)` in order to coordinate when to refresh the UI.